# Is a continuous function on a bounded set bounded itself?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

If $f\colon A\to\mathbb R$ is continuous and $A$ is a bounded set, does it necessarily follow that $f$ is bounded?

Answer (score 19):

Consider $f(x) = \dfrac1x$ on $A = (0,1)$.

Answer (score 9):

The answer is No.

But

If a function f is uniformly continuous, then f is bounded on A also.