# Bounded sets under a continuous map

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, continuity

See [Bounded set under a continuous map](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/468570/is-a-continuous-function-on-a-bounded-set-bounded-itself)

From this, I know that if $f : A \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and $A$ is bounded, then $f(A)$ need not be bounded.

What if $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is bounded, then is $f(A)$ necessarily bounded?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. If $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is bounded, then $A$ is contained in some compact set $K \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. The continuous image of a compact set is compact, and thus bounded. So we have $f(A) \subseteq f(K)$ which is bounded, and thus $f(A)$ is as well.

Comment: What about $A = (-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2})$ with $\tan$ (restricted to this domain, is $\tan$ not continuous)? Your argument looks right, but I didn't know I had this misconception

Comment: The domain of $\tan$ is not $\mathbb{R}$. OP's question is specifically about a function whose domain is  all of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: ooooh - all is right with the world. Thanks ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be bounded.
Then Closure of $A$ is compact by Heini Borel property. 
Continuity of $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$ guaranttes the continuity of $f$ on closure of $A$.
Since $cl(A)$ is compact, $f$ is continuous implies $f(cl(A))$ is compact. Hence $f$ is bounded on $cl(A)$ and hence is must be bounded on $A$.